# What's earlier than an early bird?

Tags: phrase-requests

The term early bird is well known. What's a similarly well known thing that is earlier than an early bird?

Edit: the worm, of course! But I'm particularly looking for an improvement on the bird, something that pips the bird to the post.

Comment: "Up with the chickens" is another phrase, but since chickens are birds I guess that's just a special case of "early bird".

Comment: Could it be the worm?

Comment: A night owl who just doesnt sleep

Comment: The early bird may get the worm, but it's the second mouse that gets the cheese...

Answer (score 7):

Are night owls earlier than early birds?

Comment: Actually, they are later than all others. :) We use "owl" for a person who gets up well past midday and goes to bed past midnight.

Comment: Night owls are occasionally still up at dawn, but it's not the way to bet. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I guess that would be the worm, but you don't want to be that guy.

Comment: Hahaha, yes! Anything else?

Comment: I gave you +1, but now I am reconsidering it - the really successful and effective early bird will get up 1) before other birds *and* 2) (just) before the worms :)

Comment: The early bird gets the worm - but who wants to eat worms?

Comment: Thanks to you all I am now picturing a punctual and informed avian predator poised beside a wormhole waiting for its quarry to emerge for its morning wriggle.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of an actor (other than the worm :-) ), but we sometimes refer to people as being "up at the crack of dawn", which is probably close to bird-time.

Comment: I guess the dawn cracks when it comes up like thunder (outer China 'crost the Bay).

Comment: And of course the real heroes get up at the _[butt-crack of dawn](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002232.html)_!

Comment: @Callithumpian, thanks for the LL link.  I've been hearing the phrase for years, so the poster's surprise in turn surprised me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some one who was "**up with the lark**" might beat the generic early bird.

Answer (score 3):

After the sparrow awakens but before he sets about the worm-hunting task he must first yawn, stretch, and rub the sleep from his eyes.

But even before all this he involuntarily contibutes to the dictionary:

> ***sparrow-fart***

- [Dictionary.com entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sparrowfart)
- [Etymonline entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sparrow) (under sparrow)
- [The Free Dictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sparrowfart)
- [Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sparrow-fart) (includes a few alternative forms)

(I'm not making it up)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can be earlier than the early bird, because if there were, *that* guy would get the worm, and the early bird would miss out (and therefore would not actually be the "early bird" at all).

Comment: I'm not always picky about my breakfast but even when I'm up very early indeed seldom do I choose worms.

Comment: @phrenry, Nice answer, very philosophical.

Comment: What if that guy *is*, in point of fact, earlier than the early bird, but just doesn't happen to like worms?